# Can you always substitute the 1st (event’s) Simple Past with Past Perfect, without changing meaning?

Tags: past-vs-past-perfect

What  changes semantically, when I replace the 1st preceding event's Past Tense with Past Perfect? If no semantics change, then can I always substitute the 1st event's Past Tense with Past Perfect?

##### Example sentences based on https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/shifts.htm

> [1.] She caught the ball, and then threw it.

1.1. She **had** caught the ball, and then threw it.

> [2.] When the kids turned on the TV, they heard a buzzing sound.

2.1. When the kids **had** turned on the TV, they heard a buzzing sound.

> [3.] By the time we got there, it was too late.

3.1. By the time we got there, it <s>was</s> **had been** too late.

But compare 3 with [page 83 on *Grammar Builder Level 3*, Volume 3 (2005), by Adibah Amin, R. Eravelley, Farida J Ibrahim.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Grammar_Builder_Level_3/DsKeOwh7Nu0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the+plane+already+took+off%22&pg=PA83&printsec=frontcover)

> [image]

#### Examples based on https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/tenseconsistency.htm

> [4.]  Sam stood up and then dropped his popcorn.

4.1. Sam **had** stood up and then dropped his popcorn.

> [5.] Several people passed by and stared, but no one touched the bird.

5.1. Several people  **had** passed by and stared, but no one touched the bird.

> [6.] "So powerfully did the whole grim aspect of Ahab affect me, and the livid
> brand which streaked it, that for the first few moments I hardly noted that not a little
> of this overbearing grimness was owing to the barbaric white leg upon which he
> partly stood."

6.1. "So powerfully <s>did</s> **had** the whole grim aspect of Ahab affected me, and the livid
brand which **had** streaked it, that for the first few moments I hardly noted that not a little
of this overbearing grimness was owing to the barbaric white leg upon which he
partly stood."

> [7.] Findings from a group of 12 study patients showed that X-toperin vaccination was effective in stimulating the patient's immune system to attack the tumor cells, a function known medically as tumor-specific immune response. All the patients had recurrent, high-grade glioma, and all showed a favorable immune response.

7.1. Findings from a group of 12 study patients showed that X-toperin vaccination <s>was</s> **had been** effective in stimulating the patient's immune system to attack the tumor cells, a function known medically as tumor-specific immune response. All the patients **had** had recurrent, high-grade glioma, and all showed a favorable immune response.

Comment: Your sentence 3.1 doesn't demonstrate what you're asking about. If we got there at 8:00, then it was too late at 8:00; it hadn't necessarily been too late at 7:00.

Comment: Your example from Grammar Builder doesn't demonstrate what you're asking about. In that example, the author takes a correct past perfect form and changes it to simple past. You're asking about taking a correct simple past form and changing it to past perfect.